# Integration with Desktop Application

Tags: background, desktop

I am checking feasibility of our application with Sage Pay
Our application is a thick Desktop based software having no Web-Page or integration to website.

All of following 4 options on Sage Pay website

- Form integration
- Server integration
- Serve Inframe integration
- Direct integration

are seems to be working around web-pages

Here I am only looking if SagePay solution is feasible or not because we do not have any website to take payments. 
We need to facilitate payments to be taken into our desktop software

thanks in advance 
Avtar

Answer (score 0):

Sage Pay Direct doesn't rely on pages; it can be used in a smart client application.  You just need to make sure you set the transaction type as MOTO (Mail Order Telephone Order), I think M, so that the 3D secure dialogs aren't shown.

You're right in that all the other mechanisms will require a browser.

Remember, with Sage Pay Direct you fall directly in the net of PCI DSS compliance, so you'll probably want to make sure that you remain on the right side of that.